# ASP.NET Core Identity use different user table

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to do a web App with ASP.NET Core 3.1. I have an existing SQL Database with full of users. I have only read access to this database, so I can't change nothing.
My question is, can I somehow use it to authentication to Login instead of AspNetUsers table?
(I don't need registration, nor forget password, etc., just a safety login)

My User database has these columns: Id(varchar),Name(varchar),Rank(int),Password(varchar),Email(varchar),Phone(varchar)

Comment: Yes, the system is very configurable and extendable. It’s not always that simple, but you can provide your own implementation of users, roles, etc from any storage and then let the system handle the rest. There’s documentation around for these cases

Comment: *My User table has these columns. Sorry

Comment: Could you send me some documents please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use it to authentication to Login instead of AspNetUsers table

Below is a demo, you can refer to it.

LoginModel

```
public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool RememberLogin { get; set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    }
```

UserModel

```
public class UserModel
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }
```

AccountController
**[Note]** I set fake data, you can get it directly from the database.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //Sample Users Data, it can be fetched with the use of any ORM
        public List<UserModel> users = null;
        public AccountController()
        {
            users = new List<UserModel>();
            users.Add(new UserModel() { UserId = 1, Username = "Anoop", Password = "123", Role = "Admin" });
            users.Add(new UserModel() { UserId = 2, Username = "Other", Password = "123", Role = "User" });
        }

        public IActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl = "/")
        {
            LoginModel objLoginModel = new LoginModel();
            objLoginModel.ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl;
            return View(objLoginModel);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel objLoginModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = users.Where(x => x.Username == objLoginModel.UserName && x.Password == objLoginModel.Password).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user == null)
                {
                    //Add logic here to display some message to user
                    ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Credential";
                    return View(objLoginModel);
                }
                else
                {
                    //A claim is a statement about a subject by an issuer and
                    //represent attributes of the subject that are useful in the context of authentication and authorization operations.
                    var claims = new List<Claim>() {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,Convert.ToString(user.UserId)),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,user.Username),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,user.Role),
                    new Claim("FavoriteDrink","Tea")
                    };

                    //Initialize a new instance of the ClaimsIdentity with the claims and authentication scheme
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    //Initialize a new instance of the ClaimsPrincipal with ClaimsIdentity
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    //SignInAsync is a Extension method for Sign in a principal for the specified scheme.
                    //await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    //    principal, new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = objLoginModel.RememberLogin });
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                       principal, new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = objLoginModel.RememberLogin });

                    return LocalRedirect(objLoginModel.ReturnUrl);
                }
            }
            return View(objLoginModel);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> LogOut() {

      
            //SignOutAsync is Extension method for SignOut
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            //Redirect to home page
            return LocalRedirect("/");
        }
    }
```

In  HomeController, use  `[Authorize]` on  ConfidentialData() method

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult ConfidentialData() 
        {
            return View();    
        }
    }
```

ConfidentialData view

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Confidential Data";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Confidential Data</h2>

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        @foreach (var claim in User.Claims) {
        <tr><td>@claim.Type</td><td>@claim.Value</td></tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Register Authentication in startup

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(x => x.LoginPath = "/account/login");

...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Result:

[image]

Read [Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know more.

Login form

```
@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Login</h2>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Login">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Message))
            {
                <span class="text-danger">
                    @ViewBag.Message
                </span>
            }
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ReturnUrl)
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input asp-for="RememberLogin" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RememberLogin)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! You did the Login Form, or you used the Identity Login Form?

Comment: @kajahun123 I did the Login Form.